# Get playback video position while it's running in the background

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have an app [TV] that playbacks video.
I also implemented function that when I go to background (home button), video keeps playing in background.

When I reopen video by clicking on "Now playing card" video starts from the start. I thought I could give a position and use `seekTo` method. Problem is, I'm not sure how to get currect time. Where should I call `getCurrentPosition();` as I can not use it onPause(), because while I'm in background there will be extra time spent and in the end, the time wont match.

Comment: put some code in the question

Comment: I'm more interested in asking about the idea and possibilities on this topic. I'm using ExoPlayer as my player. And implementation is similar to "Now playing card" and "Background playback" in android doc.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had a newly made activity everytime I clicked "Now playing card".
All I needed to do was to add a single line `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in my android manifest file to avoid that.

Example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SingleTaskActivity"
    android:label="singleTask launchMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
```